# How to create a custom directive that wraps others custom directive inserted dynamically into the wrapper’s template?

Tags: angularjs

I’d like to create a custom directive that wraps others custom directive inserted dynamically into the wrapper’s template.
But I can’t find a proper way to do it.
By now I’ve come up with the following solution that unfortunately doesn’t work.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('contentDir', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div><b>Content is here</b></div>'
        };
    })
    .directive('wrapperDir', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                htmlContent: '@htmlContent',
            },
            replace: true,
            controller: function($scope, $sce){
                $scope.sContent = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.htmlContent);
            },
            template: '<div>This is a wrapper for the... <span ng-bind-html="sContent"></span>!</div>'
        };
    })
;
```

//html

```
<wrapper-dir html-content="<content-dir></content-dir>"></wrapper-dir>
```

The wrapper-dir directive doesn't produce html. Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong and what the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) on wrapperDir and then you can use at html the desired inner html/directives:

```
    .directive('wrapperDir', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope, $sce){

        },
        template: '<div>This is a wrapper for the... <span ng-transclude></span>!</div>'
        };
    });
```

At html:

```
<wrapper-dir><content-dir></content-dir></wrapper-dir>
```

Answer (score 1):

For $compile I was using similar code then in your example:

```
yourApp.directive('compileBindedHtml', ['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.compileBindedHtml, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                elem.html(newValue);
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
            }
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

and then in the code:

```
<div compile-binded-html="titleHtml"></div>
```

where titleHtml is the variable contains html/angular template code.

In yours example there should be just missing part:

```
$compile(elem.contents())(scope);
```

that compile content of the element to parse angular template and bind with the scope.

Maybe this will answer your question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

But can't you just simple wrap contentDir inside the wrapperDir like that:

```
.directive('wrapperDir', function () {
    return {
        ...
        template: '<div><span>This is a wrapper for the... </span><span><content-dir></content-dir></span><span>!</span></div>'
    };
})
```

and then just using:

```
<wrapper-dir></wrapper-dir>
```

Comment: Nope. I'm gonna use lots of other directives instead of content-dir. By now I've found that I should use $compile service to compile my template. I'm figuring out the proper way...